# Can you use GIF in Delphi 11?

Tags: delphi, animation, gif, animated-gif

Is there a way to use GIFs in Delphi 11? I tried several different ways and I never get a result.

I tried to install the TRxLib package, but inside it does not come with RXgifAnimated, as I had read in a question. Maybe because mine is Delphi 11?

Well, is there a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `TImage` to display an animated GIF image.

Example:

1. add a `TImage` to a form
2. load a `GIF` image to the `TImage`
3. in a button click handler write following code:

Note! If you don't load a GIF image at design time, you must manually add the `Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg` unit to the `uses`.

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with (Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGifImage) do
  begin
    AnimationSpeed := 100;  // percent of normal speed, range 0 through 1000
    Animate := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ah, `TTimer`-based. Didn't know VCL has this support out of the box. But animated GIFs are a bit dated, especially given the colour count restriction.

Comment: Yes @Andreas, we don't need those units from Anders Melander or Finn ? (is it Tolderlund) anymore.

Comment: [`TGifImage`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.TGIFImage) has been built-in to the VCL for a long time. It is in the `Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg` unit.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I know, but I didn't know it supported animating a GIF in a `TImage`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand yup, `TGifImage` has supported that ever since it was first added to the VCL in RADStudio 2007/2009 (actually, it supported that even in [Anders' original code](http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/)).

Comment: @TomBrunberg Appreciate! Solved my problem.!